# Focus on Textfield on Application Launch cocoa mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, focus, nstextfield, launching-application

I'm trying to have an nstextfield be selected when the application launches so that the user doesn't have to click on the text field before typing. How would I go about doing this?
I've tried using the following:

`- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [mainText becomeFirstResponder];
}`

Comment: You've tried using mentioned code, but you don't write how it doesn't do what you want. What does you code do and how does it differ from what you try to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
 [mainText.window makeFirstResponder:mainText];
```

instead of:

```
[mainText becomeFirstResponder];
```